# Exclude keys from nested objects

Tags: api, rest, parse-platform

is there a way in parse server to exclude keys from nested objects?
I'm talking about doing something like this:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'excludeKeys=player.profile' \
  https://YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE/parse/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm
```

I've tried and this excludes the whole player key, while I only want to exclude player.profile.
Thanks.

Comment: Currently it is not possible. You will have to select all that you want to select (instead of excluding the ones you don't want).

Comment: Unfortunately, even adding keys with the keys parameter doesn't work if you want to only insert a property of an object. I've opened a request here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/7390#issuecomment-845083794 it seems there is already a PR for that, I hope it will be merged soon.

Comment: `curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \  --data-urlencode 'include=player' \
  --data-urlencode 'keys=player.profile' \
  https://YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE/parse/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm` should work returning only player.profile (+ the other default columns)

Comment: That doesn't work, I've solved this issue removing the properties from the cloud with an afterFind trigger.